# The usage of genitive forms

Tags: word-choice

Original:

> "Ich möchte, dass du erfährst wie schwer das Leben außerhalb dieses Schlosses ist. Nur dann wirst du zur Besinnung kommen", sagte er böse.

Google translated:

> "I want you to know how hard is life outside of this castle. Only then you will come to their senses," he said angrily.

The German word *dieses* means *these* in English, so "these castles"? And why should there be put an article before *Schlosses*, doesn't *Schlosses* refer to a general category?

Comment: Our question & answer format is designed to provide one question with one best answer. Selecting an answer that fits best to your question will not work out good if there were more than one question in a post. Therefore please avoid asking two issues in one question. It would be great if you can make an [edit] to your post to achieve this. Then you should also think of a title that better reflects your question. At present it is only a quote without a question. This will not help future visitors who may come here.

Comment: Hm, your title implies a question about genitive. While "Schlosses" is indeed the genitive form, your actual question is about the word "dieses". So, your title is not in sync with the body. – There's also a comma missing in your original between "erfährst" and "wie". I didn't fix it as I'm not sure if you appropriately quoted something and your source already contains that error.

Comment: @Em1 I just began to learn german grammar not long ago, so interpreting "dieses" as "these" is normal. Problems in my question should be acceptable as a result.

Comment: I suggest a new close reason “contains machine translation” :)

Comment: What made you think "dieses" means "these"? Did you look it up?

Comment: I vote to close, because the question in the thread is based on the (mistaken) OP's opinion that *dieses* means *these*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't believe everything what Google Translate offers to you. But, nevertheless, the translation is surprisingly good.

**1.** It should be:

> Only then you will come round to **your senses**.

In this sentence there is nowhere the word "they" or "their".

**2.** Look at your translation, Google got it correct.

> Life outside of this castle

*This castle* -> **Dieses Schloss**, and now in Genitiv: *of this castle* --> **dieses Schloss*es***. English *these* translates as **diese**.

For more reading and understanding, please google for: Genitiv forms, definite articles, the pronoun *diese/r/s*.

Comment: Hey, could you change "I wouldn't believe everything" to "I wouldn't believe anything" ;) – I mean, very basic and simple sentences are translated corrected more often than not; but when it comes to a more complicated sentence, Google fails.

Comment: "wouldn't believe everything" means that some of, even most of, but not all of those give by google translate are flawed, "... anything" means that google translate is always wrong about anything.

Comment: @pxc3110 That was my point. My intent was to state that Google is always wrong. But there is a smiley that also indicates that I wasn't too serious about that and I acknowledged that there are cases where Google is correct (simple sentences).

Comment: @Barth Your answering is missing one thing, though. The reason why the article (or rather pronoun) is used.

Comment: If you do not know English well then it's fine. I already found that funny in the beginning:)

Comment: If "diese Schlosses" means "this castle" then I totally understand why there is an article.